# nginx as dynamic reverse proxy not working

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy but with dynamic destination IP/ports and I've not been able to get it working. At this stage I'd like to know if what I'm trying to achieve is actually possible.

I'd like to add the remote IP address/hostname and IP address in the original request and then use that as the proxy_pass so that nginx will forward that request accordingly.

If I use this as my `reverse_proxy.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name server.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server2.com:8080;
    }
}
```

It works correctly and and request from `https://server.com` goes to `http://server2.com:8080`

What I am trying to achieve is to do this dynamically, so that if I use go to this URL:

```
https://server.com/?uri=http://server2.com:8080
```

It will take the URL entered as the variable 'uri' and perform the same task as above.

This is what I have tried:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name server.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass $arg_uri;
    }
}
```

But if I do this, I get this error:

```
2020/05/05 04:12:31 [error] 36608#36608: *2 invalid URL prefix in ""
```

So I tried changing `proxy_pass $arg_uri;` to `proxy_pass http://$arg_uri;` but then just get `invalid URL prefix in "http://"` in the error.log

Can what I'm trying to do be done? If so, what am I missing?

UPDATE : This is what appears in access.log

```
xxx.156.127.xxx - - [07/May/2020:21:28:15 +0100] "GET /?uri=http://server2.com:8080 HTTP/1.1" 500 595 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
xxx.156.127.xxx - - [07/May/2020:21:28:15 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 595 "https://server.com/?uri=http://server2.com:8080" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
```

And in error .log

```
2020/05/07 21:29:52 [error] 38723#38723: *5 invalid port in upstream "http://server2.com:8080", client: xxx.156.127.xxx, server: server.com, request: "GET /?uri=http://server2.com:8080 HTTP/1.1", host: "server.com"
2020/05/07 21:29:52 [error] 38723#38723: *6 invalid URL prefix in "http://", client: xxx.156.127.xxx, server: server.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "server.com", referrer: "https://server.com/?uri=http://server2.com:8080"
```

Comment: What does the access log say? Most web pages are constructed from multiple URLs, and only the initial request will have your magic argument.

Comment: @RichardSmith I have updated with what is displayed in both access.log and error.log

Comment: The second error is obvious. The browser is requesting `/favicon.ico` which is missing your `uri` argument.